# Mercurial - Class files not showing in on hg status

Tags: mercurial

I have many java classes in my local repository and I remember they showed up when I wrote **hg status**. Now I don't see them anymore although they still exist!

What happened here, and how do I make **hg status** show them again?

Comment: Do you have a `.hgignore` file in the root of your repository? Does `hg config | grep ignore` show any additional files that are used to specify ignore patterns?

Comment: I have a `.hgignore` file but it contains only two classes. I had the same `.hgignore` file before and the unignored classes did show. Now they don't...

Comment: Are there already revisions in your repository for these classes, or are they entirely new? If not new, are they actually changed? Did you shelve or commit the changes already?

Comment: Yes there are already revisions. I did commit the changes

Comment: For some reason if I delete these files manually - hg status shows them! What should I do?

Comment: Then there were no changes to those files, as far as mercurial was concerned. Are you sure you saved your changes in your editor?

Comment: So if there are no changes, I won't see them on hg status?

Comment: Exactly, `hg status` only shows files that added, deleted or changed relative to the working copy parent revision.

Comment: If you want to see all files, use `hg status --all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hg status`, by default, only shows files that have *changed* in some way (are new, have been deleted, or have been altered relative to the working copy parent).

From the `hg status --help` page:

> Show status of files in the repository. If names are given, only files
>       that match are shown. Files that are clean or ignored or the source of a
>       copy/move operation, are not listed unless -c/--clean, -i/--ignored,
>       -C/--copies or -A/--all are given.

If you haven't made any changes to your class files, `hg status` won't list them unless you ask it specifically for the status of that file (`hg status path/to/classfile`) or ask it to list all files or all *clean* files (those that are not changed), with `hg status --clean`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to this.